# How to get video in coral dev board using OPENCV?

Tags: python, opencv, google-coral

How trigger the coral dev board camera from opencv

---

cv.VideoCapture(0)

i am using this command to trigger the camera in opencv python. unfortunately it is giving error. not triggering the camera.

please let me know code for opencv python in coral dev board.

Comment: You say it is giving an error. Please say what error you are seeing.

Comment: my version of opencv is 3.2.0 and giving error like 

OpenCV Error: (-215)size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function ...

Comment: import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
cap=cv.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    _,frame= cap.read()
    cv.imshow("name", frames)
    key=cv.waitKey(1)
    if key==27:                              # 27 for esc key
        break
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()

Comment: Please edit the question and add this information in. It will make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using usb camera you should use;

```
cv.VideoCapture(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm from the coral team, just wanted to update on the issue here so that other can reference.

- This is not caused by OpenCV, I have a full code with errors and it looks fine.
- The usage of the library is correct.

The error is due to cv not able to read any data off from `/dev/video0`. At this stage I believe it's just bad connection between the camera sensors and the camera board. A command to take a picture from the camera failed.

Comment: Hi, I tried to check the sensor connection with the camera board and coral board.

Comment: Connections are fine, I connected well.  but snapshot --oneshot in bulid application commands also not working.

Comment: Error coming like :   /user/bin/snapshot:117: PYGIDeprecationwarning: Gobject.mainloop is desprecated; use Glib.Mainloop instead. loop= Gobject.Mainloop()